# Trying to Change LaTeX Template's Bullet Points

Tags: lists, cv, resume

I am creating a resume using a template I found online.  I am nearly done, however I want to bring the bullet points closer together!  There are two files in my project: `cv_4.tex` and `resume.cls`.  The code below is found in the `resume.cls` file.  I tried to change the numbers, but nothing worked.

The template I am using is found here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv

```
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you supply an complete example (MWE) not only containing this definition, but also a document in which you use it?

Comment: I apologize I will make sure to next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the space between the neighbor bullets then changing value after `\itemsep` works fine (e.g. `-1em` will make them closer, while `0em` will add more space between the bullets.

However, just adding or removing space between the bullets while ignoring line space makes bullets pretty ugly: you may get space between lines in the same bullet bigger then space between neighbor bullets. You can change the line spacing inside the list e.g. by wrapping the list into `spacing` environment (provided by package `setspace`). See this example, changes comparing to the original are lines 120, 126 and 28

http://papeeria.com/p/3a0f9ae94cb2a9f9e0a96a8efe0b9061#/resume.cls

Comment: @Alan you may want to mark it as the answer

Comment: dmitry thank you so much for taking your time to help me! you did an awesome job